How to assign contact to the Opportunity Owner field, rather than limiting the selection to users
I would like to select a contact name in the Opportunity Owner field instead of the users after creating the record.
Is this possible in Salesforce? Could someone help guide me on the possibilities and limitations?

Fundamentally, no. This is either a User ID or a Group ID. Contact ID is not supported. You could create a Group representing the Contact, but that seems... pointless. This might help your understanding.

Only Users can own any kind of record, never Contacts.  If you need to associate a contact with an opportunity, you can use the standard Opportunity Contact Role feature, see the documentation.
